# User isn't authenticated till the next page request

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, authentication, profile

I have this following mvc application

The problem is when Im trying to assign profile values:

```
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(model.Email, model.Password);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                //Adding role
                MembershipService.AddDefaultRole(model.Email);

                FormsService.SignIn(model.Email, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

                //Add other initial profile data
                HttpContext.Profile["FirstName"] = model.FirstName; //PROBLEM
                HttpContext.Profile["LastName"] = model.LastName; //PROBLEM

                return RedirectToAction("List", new { area = "", controller = "Requests" });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountValidation.ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
```

Inside FormsService.SignIn(model.Email, false):

```
    public void SignIn(string email, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "email");

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, createPersistentCookie);
    }
```

How come after calling FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie, User isn't yet authenticated?
I'm getting an error b.c. im trying to assign some profile value to anonymous user .

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a cookie, it's added to the Response, but the IsAuthenticated bool is set from the Request.  After setting the authentication and setting up your session variables, you should redirect to another page, like the home page or the original request.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know any easy way to update profile value before the next request then?  or should I store the values temporarily and save it on the next page request? What's the proper way of doing it?

Comment: Do you need to? in your initialization event, if the user is authenticated but does not have profile information, I would think that's the time to load it up, but I've never used the built-in profile manager, it never suited my needs.